# Using munin for server monitoring

Tags: ubuntu, munin, graph

I want to use munin for monitoring my VPS servers. I'm just interested is it possible to use it without apache installing? So is it possible to install only munin-node on each node I want to monitor and install munin and apache only on my laptop MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it won't work very well.  The central munin server needs to poll the nodes every five minutes to keep a continuous record of the data; if you run it on a laptop, then the data will only be polled, the rrd files maintained, and the graphs updated, while the laptop is on and connected.  The rest of the time the data will be lost, as `munin-node` doesn't keep historical data.

You would do better to run the central munin server, and associated `httpd`, on just one of the VPSes, and have it collect the data from all the other servers via their local `munin-node` processes.  Better still, if you can afford it, is to run a custom VPS as the central monitoring server; that way none of your real nodes need run anything other than a `munin-node`, as you want, but the data will still be collected and processed in real-time.

**Edit**: a properly-configured `munin` is very lightweight.  You need to make sure that the `munin-node`s will only accept requests from the munin master, and that `httpd` is configured not to allow anyone to access it vexatiously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I to reside munin server on of the my nodejs servers, does it impact to their performance?